# OpenGL gluUnProject object drag and camera Issue

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to move an object with the mouse:

I retrieve the actual matrixes and use gluUnProject to obtain the actual x,y,z from the mouse position dx and dy.It all works fine till I don't move the camera.It works fine when camera is at 45,225 degrees starting from X axis.

[image: Working fine here]
But when I am going near x(+-)\z(+-) axis that's the behaviour (the plan on which the object should move is not updated correctly)

[image]
Things I do on mouse click events:

```
gluUnProject(event->x(), -event->y(), 0, model_matrix, proj_matrix, view_matrix, &newx, &newy, &newz);
    //dx and dy = mouse coords
    if (dy<dx){
        if (event->x()>mNewMousePosition.x()){
            emit SignalPreviewMouseChanged((float)(mNewx/1500)*acc,0,(float)(-mNewz/1500)*acc);
        }
        else {
            emit SignalPreviewMouseChanged((float)(-mNewx/1500)*acc,0,(float)(mNewz/1500)*acc);
        }
    }
    else{
        if (event->y()<mNewMousePosition.y())
            emit SignalPreviewMouseChanged(0,(float)(mNewy/750)*acc,0);
        else {
            emit SignalPreviewMouseChanged(0,(float)(-mNewy/750)*acc,0);
        }
    }
```

That is the render method:

```
void PaintGL()
{

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();

glViewport (0, 0, mScreenWidth, mScreenHeight);

if (mRotateAroundYAxis){
    gluLookAt(mObjCamera->Pos().x,  mObjCamera->Pos().y,  mObjCamera->Pos().z,
              0, mObjCamera->View().y, 0,
              mObjCamera->Up().x,   mObjCamera->Up().y,   mObjCamera->Up().z);        
}else{
    gluLookAt(mObjCamera->Pos().x,  mObjCamera->Pos().y,  mObjCamera->Pos().z,
              mObjCamera->View().x, mObjCamera->View().y, mObjCamera->View().z,
              mObjCamera->Up().x,   mObjCamera->Up().y,   mObjCamera->Up().z);            
}

glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, model_matrix);
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, proj_matrix);
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, view_matrix);

for (int k=0;k<mIndexSize/2;k++) {
    glCallList(mIndexSize-k);
}

DrawGrid();
DrawAxis();
}
```

Comment: One thing strikes me immediately when looking at this code, you are retrieving the modelview, projection and viewport matrices _BEFORE_ you setup your transformation... Logically, I would expect to see these things happen _AFTER_ your calls to `gluLookAt (...)`, or you will wind up using values that are at least one frame old / or uninitialized.

Comment: My apologies,while cutting and pasting code to make it simple I do this error. Matrices are set after the glulookAt (code updated). What I am noticing is that ,watching matrices values when i move the camera, projection matrix gets updated while modelview matrix is updated only when field of view is changed.

Comment: I will open for bounty in 1 day